# Не работает код matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

```
from matplotlib.projections.polar import Axes
from io import IncrementalNewlineDecoder
from matplotlib.pyplot import (axes,axis,title,legend,figure,xlabel,ylabel,xticks,yticks,xscale,yscale,text,grid,plot,scatter,errorbar,colorbar,subplots,hist,polar,contour,contourf,clabel,imshow)
from matplotlib import cm
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from numpy import *
from numpy.random import normal
from matplotlib.ticker import LinearLocator
%matplotlib inline

t=linspace(0,2*pi,50)
th,ph=meshgrid(t,t)
r=0.4
x,y,z=(1+r*cos(ph))*cos(th),(1+r*cos(ph))*sin(th),r*sin(ph)
fig=figure()
ax=Axes3D(fig)
ax.elev=60
plt = ax.plot_surface(x,y,z,rstride=2,cstride=1)
```

Этот код должен выводить на экран трехмерный график, но не выводит ничего. Что делать?

Answer (score 1):

На английском SO [есть ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76217580/8324991). Замените:

```py
ax=Axes3D(fig)
```

На правильный метод формирования 3D оси:

```py
ax = fig.add_subplot(projection='3d')
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]